# Footer is not appearing on theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to register three widget areas on the bottom of my theme. I registered the three widget areas in my functions file and it worked. I then added them to my theme and placed content in them via the Widgets admin area, but for some reason, the sidebar just isn't registering or being outputted in my on my theme.

The issue can be viewed here: http://www.noellesnotes.com (the widgets should appear at the very bottom of the page).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Here's the relevant code:

functions.php code:

```
function portfolio_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'portfolio' ),
        'id' => 'bottom-sidebar-1',
        'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h1>',
    ) );
        register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Bottom Sidebar 2',
        'id' => 'bottom-sidebar-2',
        'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h1>',
    ) );
        register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Bottom Sidebar 3',
        'id' => 'bottom-sidebar-3',
        'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'portfolio_widgets_init' );
```

sidebar.php (where the widget areas should appear):

```
<div class="bottom-sidebar shadow">
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">       
            <aside id="footer1" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>
            <aside id="footer2" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>
            <aside id="footer3" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>
        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
</div>
```

If you need anymore code, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the problem but try this code:-

```
<div class="bottom-sidebar shadow">
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">       
            <aside id="footer1" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-1');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>
            <aside id="footer2" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-2')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-2');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>
            <aside id="footer3" class="widget">
                <?php
                if(is_active_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-2')){
                dynamic_sidebar('bottom-sidebar-2');
                }
                ?>
            </aside>

    </div><!-- #secondary -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an endif; at the bottom that shouldn't be there. Try removing that.

Also the template file on the page linked won't be calling get_sidebar(); since none of the HTML is showing either.